# What is the settlement date for ACH?

Tags: united-states, ach, settling-and-clearing

DTCC requires that equities, municipal debt securities, corporate debt securities, and CDs settle T+2 and  US Treasury & Agency debt securities settle T+1.

Is there any ***strict*** settlement date for ACH transactions? Every where I look it says it's 3-7 days which doesn't seem very solid.

Comment: please see https://www.sec.gov/news/press-release/2017-68-0 and
 https://www.nacha.org/rules/same-day-ach-moving-payments-faster-phase-3

Answer (score 2):

> ACH credit and ACH debit transactions process quickly.  Settlement, or the transfer of funds from one financial institution to another to complete the transaction, generally happens next day.
>
> Specifically, the NACHA Operating Rules require that ACH credits settle in one to two business days and ACH debits settle on the next business day. Recent enhancements to the NACHA Operating Rules now enable same-day settlement of virtually all ACH transactions.

You might get a clearer answer by contacting your dealer/broker.

[SOURCE](https://www.nacha.org/news/what-ach-quick-facts-about-automated-clearing-house-ach-network)

Comment: So there's no standard is what you're saying